# GraphQl @manyToMany usage?

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, relational-database, backend, aws-amplify

I work with Amplify/`graphQl transformer V2`, I try to do the same things like the official documentation of Amplify : https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#many-to-many-relationship

So in the part of `@manyToMany` relationship, I understand that the relational Table generated automatically and in amplify studio I found all queries and mutaions... of this table.

My question is how can I add some fields in this table (relationalTable).

N.B : I'm using the same example of the documentation : https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#many-to-many-relationship so how can I add for example the field ***City*** in the `PostTags` table ?

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  content: String
  tags: [Tag] @manyToMany(relationName: "PostTags")
}

type Tag @model {
  id: ID!
  label: String!
  posts: [Post] @manyToMany(relationName: "PostTags")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to solve this problem I changed the logic to work with `@HasOne`, instead of `@ManyToMany`

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  content: String
}

type Tag @model {
  id: ID!
  label: String!
}

// Relational Table

type PostTag @model {
  id: ID!
  tag: Tag@hasOne
  post: Post@hasOne

  // Other attributes here
}
```

Comment: while this will work, is this the only solution? I am also facing the same issue. `@manyToMany` was created for a reason so I would assume you can use it as intended but the docs are not very clear. I even tried manually inserting the ids into the join table that was automatically created from using the many-to-many directive and I do not get data that i'm expecting.

Comment: Currently having a similar issue, @iamthestreets did you find a solution?

Comment: @fbelfort yes, I did find a solution that works for me. When you use `@manyToMany`, a 'join' table is created which you can insert/update data. Using the example from the OP, you can insert data into the `PostTags` table. My issue was when I tried to query data, I was not getting anything so the solution for me was to increase the statement depth. I can't remember exactly how I did it but you can try running `amplify add codegen` and increase the statement depth. If you have run this already try `amplify configure codegen`

Comment: You don't need a join table with the new v2 transformer, it will be created in the background.

Comment: you can adjust statement depth in `.graphqlconfig.yml` here:

`extensions: amplify: maxDepth: 6` (for example)